# PDF export link not displaying with display tag

Tags: jsp, struts2, displaytag

I'm coding a web app with struts2 and using the display tag. The PDF export link is not appearing, while the Excel and CSV links do.

What can I do?

This is the display tag in a JSP:

```
<display:table class="table" name="employeeBeanList" 
    pagesize="5" requestURI="EmpSummaryAction"
    export="true" decorator="EmployeePortal3.EmployeeTableDecorator">

        <display:column property="modifyLink" title="Modify"/> 
        <display:column property="deleteLink" title="Delete"/>
        <display:column property="id" title="ID" sortable="true" style="text-align:right"/>
        <display:column property="name" title="Name" sortable="true" />
        <display:column property="age" title="Age" sortable="true" style="text-align:right"/>
        <display:column property="gender" title="Gender" sortable="true"/>
        <display:column property="salary" title="Salary" sortable="true" style="text-align:right"/>
        <display:column property="department" title="Department" sortable="true"/>
        <display:column property="skills" title="Skills" sortable="true"/>
        <display:column property="address" title="Address" sortable="true"/>
        <display:column property="city" title="City" sortable="true"/>

        <!-- exports -->
        <display:setProperty name="export.pdf" value="true"/>
        <display:setProperty name="export.csv" value="true" />
        <display:setProperty name="export.excel" value="true" />
        <display:setProperty name="export.xml" value="false" />
        <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.filename" value="Employees.pdf"/>
        <display:setProperty name="export.csv.filename" value="Employees.csv"/>
        <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="Employees.xls"/>

</display:table>
```

Comment: `I have tried all help in internet` you must be a quantum computer

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

Add displaytag.properties file in your classpath (i.e in src folder).copy and paste below lines.

```
export.csv.include_header=true
export.excel=true
export.csv=true
export.xml=true
paging.banner.placement=top
```

Comment: i'm using displaytag 1.2 ,please post your stacktrace.

Comment: How to get stacktrace?, you mean log.

Answer (score -2):

Simple, replace `requestURI="EmpSummaryAction"` with `requestURI=""`.

Comment: Could you explain a bit why/how this solves the issue?